# To what extent do monetary incentives encourages researchers to publish in ISI Journals?

Tags: research-process, publications, journals

There is an argument in my institute that ISI journal publication incentive (in ISI journals only) should be omitted. However, the opposition, including me, believe that such monetary incentive would motivate young researchers who are low paid researchers to publish their work in ISI journals. I checked some of the international universities and found similar discussions tend to agree that incentive is necessary for young publishers and researchers.

What is the status in your institutes and to what extent do you think payment for ISI journal publication encourages researchers to work more seriously?

NOTEs:
1- Please consider that the focus is on legitimate peer reviewed ISI journal publication ONLY, not any other publications such as conference or predatory open access journals.

2- FYI, in Computer Science, publishing in a legitimate peer reviewed ISI journal takes from 6 months to 2 years. If a novice researcher can publish in 6 months, he/she is considered very lucky and brilliant.

Comment: Do you mean personal money or research money?  At our institute, there is significant money for each publication, but it's all research money and tied to the group as a whole (although PhD students some rights to claim part of it for work-related expenses).

Comment: without research money work is hard. No money, no research :) I mean personal money that encourages researchers to rigorously publish.

Comment: It seems like you are mixing apples and oranges here. Incentivizing authors with potential payouts won't shorten the time it takes to publish (it might actually have the opposite effect, if publications get swamped with marginal work in hopes of cash payouts). Moreover, many research efforts take years of work before they have matured enough to submit for publication. If young researchers aren't motivated by the opportunity to (a) get all that hard work prominently recognized, and (b) put their "name on the map," so to speak, I wonder how much a few hundred bucks would add to the motivation.

Comment: What are "ISI journals", "legitimate ISI journal publications", and "legitimate peer reviewed ISI journals"?

Comment: @Jukka: It's [these](http://www.bg.ump.edu.pl/czasopisma/isi/?lang=eng&lt=J).

Comment: @J.R. you are right, but we do not discuss about those big research projects that takes several years to end. The focus is more on master or PhD level works which is publishable in 1-2 years. Moreover, students have limited time to publish; so there is no time to try and fail by reducing the content for increasing the number. A good research student has chance to publish only few journal papers in 3 years of research. That money can help him not to be discouraged by out of scope decisions, long review process, loss rejections, and harsh comments, I guess.

Comment: I would think _getting a job after you finish your degree_ would be sufficient incentive to publish in reputable venues.

Comment: RE: _"That money can help him not to be discouraged by out of scope decisions .. and harsh comments."_ I don't see how it helps if the paper is ultimately rejected, because there would be no money then. There's also a chance that some of those "harsh comments" are actually legitimate criticisms of the work, and what's really needed is a mindset change. Instead of being disincentivized by the "criticisms," an author could be thankful for the feedback, and improve their paper. Sure, some criticisms are petty and some rejections pedantic, but, again, I don't see how money would fix that.

Comment: (cont.) Money might even make the situation worse. If some reviewers feel the need critique harshly to protect the integrity of the journal or profession, those same referees might be even _more_ harsh knowing that part of their dues will be lining an prospective author's pocket. You might incentivize the young author, but you might also ratchet up the criticism, too, thereby exacerbating the root problem.

Comment: Watch your wording! "Rant?" I did not ask anyone to solve any problem; I asked what is in their institute and in their own mind. Read the question carefully. In all these failures, author will likely give up for any reason (injustice or even insufficient and insignificant work). Point is not why referees reject; but is that incentive may fuel desperate young researcher's engine to restart and work to improve the quality and address comments to publish it.

Comment: @J.R. and Espanta: Please avoid long discussion on the comment thread. If something is not clear about the question, you can discuss it in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) or on [meta](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Espanta: For the record, my "rant" remark was not directed at your original question, but at your six subsequent comments. Nonetheless, I've deleted that comment, since it seemed to offend you.

Comment: I'm sure you come from Iran. The single country in the world which blindly values the so-called "ISI journals". The value of a paper definitely is not defined by such rough categorization.

Comment: @coderinnetwork thanks for your hard work to connect me to a country without having enough clue on what you are talking about! Probably Iran is the only country you know in the world. Better to study more and think twice before labeling a country as this or that. Please go and read about research funds in Malaysia, Singapore, Korea, Pakistan, Turkey, Saudi Arabia, Qatar and many other countries who hire researchers for ISI papers to elevate in World rankings for attracting intl students.

Comment: @Espanta No problem.

Comment: Although it seems incomprehensible for veterans, it is also kind of true that master and phd students are being treated like 'slaves' considering of their low payment or none at all. Academia world tends to value volunteerism and expect it from other people too. From the academician's point of view, the low payment also relates with the quality of the students' work, most students' work quality could not rival the veterans. But the low income of master and phd students is not false afaik and quite saddening. Often, academicians' salaries are even less than other industries' too (depends).

Comment: Also, I think the region plays a major part too. Developing countries tend to pursue more ISI journals because that's what the higher-ups set as success/hiring measures. Also researchers from developed countries has far more research budget due to their culture appreciating research more, can afford giving more money to research than to alleviate the poor people and developing the country (for example), and the huge gap of currency. Thus, young researchers in developing countries are much more lower-paid than the developed-countries' counterparts. just my opinion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the status in your institutes and to what extent do you think payment for publication encourage researchers to work more seriously?

I've never worked in an environment with payment for publication, so my impressions are based on observing it from the outside.  I'm sure it encourages publishing more papers, but publishing more papers is different from working more seriously:

1. Publication payments encourage mediocre submissions, since success is defined by having a paper in a certain type of journal, regardless of how good or bad the paper is.  In many cases the optimal strategy is not to work hard on writing a few excellent papers, but rather to write as many mediocre papers as possible and then submit them repeatedly in a search for lenient editors and reviewers.
2. In addition to the quality issue, payments per paper create an incentive to break work up into [least publishable units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_publishable_unit).
3. Publication payments complicate coauthorship decisions, based on how the money is awarded.  If every coauthor receives a fixed amount, then it creates a financial incentive to add honorary authors.  On the other hand, if a fixed amount of money is divided among all the authors, then it creates an incentive to remove less important but legitimate authors.  (And if it's just the "first author," then that magnifies the importance of who that author is.)  Either way, authorship is being decided based partly on financial pressure, rather than intellectual contributions.

Of course, all these issues are already serious problems in academia, with or without publication payments, but adding direct financial incentives just makes them worse.  In addition, using a fixed formula heightens the tension by removing ambiguity.  With hiring, one might worry that hiring committees will count papers instead of judging their quality, but at least some of them will prefer two great papers to five mediocre ones.  By contrast, the incentives with publication payments are unambiguous, which strengthens their effects.

Comment: I guess (not sure) world university ranking agencies need publication multiplicity when ranking universities and this is what growing universities need. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: Your points 1--3 are a perfect example of Goodhart's law: "When a measure becomes a target, it ceases to be a good measure."

Comment: _this is what growing universities need_ — [citation needed]

Comment: "I guess" indicates that there is no citations and is personal guess only.

Answer (score 7):

There is one incentive: **publish or perish**.

Without publishing, young researchers will have a limited chance of a good career in academia. Without good publications, obtaining grant money will be difficult. Without grant money, you will be given more teaching duties and less chance to research. Without publications, you will not be granted tenure. You may end up with a teaching position, which is fine if that's what you want, but the chances of doing research will diminish.

Telling a long term story is perhaps a good way of motivating students.

We certainly don't pay them to publish, though they do get the opportunity to go to conferences to present their work, but only if they have work to present.

Comment: Your point about grant money is interesting. One could argue that, if the research was funded with grant money, you've already been paid to do the research, so why should you get paid again to publish the results? That would be like double-dipping.

Comment: @J.R. Possibly, except one never actually sees any of the grant money as cash-in-hand.

Comment: @J.R. Many young researchers, especially students are low paid researchers who have no interest to publish, but to finish their study and get the degree. Especially for those students who are under pressure of publishing paper in ISI journals (not all ISI journals, valid and high quality journals, no predatory journal) incentive can be a hoping point.

Comment: @Espanta: I guess you are not talking about PhD students. PhD students who have no interest in publishing  are in the wrong business.

Comment: @DaveClarke: As you mentioned, without publication there is limited chance of good academic career. But, still money is a vital need of human. If you have $10000 in account you surely survive for a while, but if you have 1 or 2 ISI paper, you may not survive unless someone employ you. Though publication facilitates and enhances chance of recruitment, still it is a marginal privilege. Also, what about those who are not interested to be in academia? Many need to learn research for industry. Do they need publication? do they perish without publication? can't we pay & ask them to publish?

Comment: @DaveClarke, MANY young researchers, not all of them ;). PhD is not all about publication, right? PhD is a comprehensive training program and is the highest educational program. Publication is only one step of it. I know many of my friends and colleagues pursuing/ending their PhD who hate publication and are/becoming a successful industrialist. Though I have published more than 7 papers in my 2 years of PhD, still what I learnt from PhD is more than what I learnt from publication.

Comment: @Espanta: A PhD is about research. I really question the value of doing research if it is not published. In our faculty, you cannot receive a PhD unless you have published.

Comment: @DaveClarke: I have no argument about publication itself. One may publish his work in a conference in 2 months (in normal review process) and get 1000 citations out of that, that is absolutely right. But what I am arguing is the journal publication which may take upto 2 years to get accepted. After 12 month and 3 stage of revisions one of my colleagues paper is rejected based on silly excuse. Look at publication from this perspective too.

Comment: @Espanta: The fact that the question was about journals only was not clear.

Comment: @DaveClarke: Thanks, I further modify the question. If further modification needed pls donot hesitate to do it. I appreciate that.